# How to reset resolution on raspbian

Tags: raspbian

I wanted my entire monitor to be filled, so I set the resolution way too high by accident and now when I try to change it I can't pull the window high enough to click ok.

Comment: Just a thought, but you may be able to plug it into a TV. Also, try resizing the window. If those don't work: `xrandr -q | grep "connected primary"` then `xrandr --output HDMI-0 --auto` -- assuming the primary device is HDMI-0.

Answer (score 4):

If you put the SD Card in a computer you should be able to set the resolution by editing `config.txt`.

If you uncomment the line `hdmi_safe=1` you should get a display.

```
# uncomment if you get no picture on HDMI for a default "safe" mode
#hdmi_safe=1
```

Depending on your monitor and how you changed it you may have something like the following.
Mine is :-

```
# uncomment to force a specific HDMI mode (this will force VGA)
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=35
```

(35 is 1280x1024    60Hz)

You can see supported values in https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/video.md

Comment: A better first test is to add `#` to EVERY line in config.txt to allow the display & the RPi to exchange EDID data and see if there's a display mode that works. Get rid of all hdmi, all framebuffer & all overscan lines. If that doesn't work add each overscan line in one at a time until things work normally.

Comment: I had the same problem, I followed the recommendation from @Milliways and that worked. To fix the problem I went through opened up the config.txt and commented out all of the settings and then reboot. That allowed the system to detect the best settings and restored my view. > SPEC: Raspberry Pi B+ running Raspberry Pi OS Stretch